# \NewDocumentCommand not working in pgfplots when \newcommand does

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, macros, xparse

I'm currently trying to update some LaTeX code. I want to replace `\newcommand` with `\NewDocumentCommand`. Most of the time it works fine, but I have problems with the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\newcommand{\coords}{(1,1)}  % works
%\NewDocumentCommand{\coords}{}{(1,1)}  % does not work

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot coordinates {(0,0) \coords};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

With `\newcommand` it works fine, but with `\NewDocumentCommand` I get the error

```
Incomplete \ifx; all text was ignored after line 11.
```

What is the difference between `\newcommand` and `\NewDocumentCommand`, that causes the error? If I understand correctly, `\NewDocumentCommand` always declares robust commands. Is this the problem here?

How can I still use `\NewDocumentCommand`? (Or something similar that allows to define commands with multiple optional arguments with custom delimiters)

Comment: How about `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand`? ;-)

Comment: @gusbrs Thanks, but that doesn't seem to work either :/

Comment: \NewDocumentCommand is robust and typically not suited for this kind of commands.

Comment: @user187803 Indeed it doesn't. I don't know the culprit then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pgfplots` does one-step expansion when it encounters a control sequence in `<coordinates list>` from input `\addplot ... coordinates {<coordinates list>}`, see [`\pgfplots@foreach@plot@coord@ITERATE@`](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgfplots/blob/6fdb6210692c35fd7e5f71a26594944ae3ac81b9/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotscoordprocessing.code.tex#L4699-L4727).

This looks fine and fits commands defined by `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand` just right, but in general one-step expansion is not enough. When a macro (or the expansion of its replacement text) contains conditionals like `\ifx`, one-step expansion will leave incomplete `\ifxxx`.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
% show result of one-step expansion of `\ifx\a\b true\else false\fi`
\ttfamily
\detokenize\expandafter{\ifx\a\b true\else false\fi} % leave "false\fi"
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand`-defined commands do use conditionals. In OP's example, for `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\coords}{}{(1,1)}` the first encountered conditional is `\token_if_eq_charcode:NNT`.

Since `<coordinates list>` ignores spaces and a coordinate won't start with digits, `+`, or `-`, it seems safe to do a `\romannumeral` expansion. Explanations of `` \romannumeral-`\0 `` used below can be found on this site.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
% originally defined in pgfplotscoordprocessing.code.tex
\xpatchcmd\pgfplots@foreach@plot@coord@ITERATE@
  {
    \if\noexpand\pgfplots@foreach@plot@coord@ITERATE@tok\noexpand\anymacro
          % Ah. #1 has the same character (!) code as \anymacro,
          % that means it is a macro! Expand it:
      \def\pgfplots@loop@next{%
        \expandafter\pgfplots@foreach@plot@coord@ITERATE#1}%
  }{%
    \if\noexpand\pgfplots@foreach@plot@coord@ITERATE@tok\noexpand\anymacro
      \def\pgfplots@loop@next{%
        \expandafter\pgfplots@foreach@plot@coord@ITERATE\romannumeral-`\0#1}%
  }
  {}{\PatchFailed}
\makeatother

%\newcommand{\coords}{(1,1)}  % works
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\coords}{}{(1,1)} % works now

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot coordinates {(0,0) \coords};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

PS: I'm curious about why you'd like to define `\coord` by `xparse` (or, as it's now part of the kernel, the `ltcmd` module) commands, when `\def` or `\newcommand` already fits the requirement.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. About your PS: The example I give in my question is what I identified as one core problem, so it is stripped down very much. However, eventually, I want to have a macro `\foo` that accepts (optional) arguments of the form `\foo<...>[...]{...}` (hence `\NewDocumentCommand`) and, also, `\foo` will be used more generally, not only in `pgfplots`. (Actually, I'm talking about the macro `\py` in the `pyluatex` package of which I'm the author. Currently, it doesn't accept optional arguments).

Comment: My suggestion is to construct a new no-arg macro and append needed data to it (in `\py`). Supporting arbitrary arg-spec `xparse` commands in anywhere is a nightmare, but supporting a no-arg macro is much easier.

Comment: With the no-arg approach you mean something similar to @frougon's answer? If I get your answer right, without patching `pgfplots`, there is also no way to get it working with an optional argument to `\newcommand`, because with an optional argument, one-step expansion does no longer expand the macro fully. Do you agree?

Comment: Yes, I mean sth like `\def\macro{<result of python code>}`. The opt-arg detection used by `\newcommand`-defined commands relies on `\futurelet` hence is unexpandable. `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand`-defined commands use an expandable way to detect opt-arg, with some restrictions (see `texdoc xparse`, sec. 3.3). But I believe that new way relies on conditionals (like `\if`) hence still won't work in pgfplots, without patching.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the insights

Answer (score 2):

`\NewDocumentCommand` defines `\protected` macros. As such, they aren't expanded inside `\edef`, `\write`, etc. The macros defined by `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand` don't have this property, so it is a natural idea to try it here... but this doesn't work, as mentioned in the comments. Finding out why may be complicated, I'll leave this to the experts!

But here is a strategy that essentially always works when you can't do what you want in a “sensitive place” (typically, an expansion-only context):

1. You do the “complex work” *before* TeX reaches the sensitive place. You should choose a place where TeX performs expansion *and* execution; this way, you can use all the tools you want for the task (including `\NewDocumentCommand` or any other non-expandable tooling).
2. From this place, you store the result in a macro (in `expl3`, the “result macro” in `*_set_*` functions like `\seq_set_split:Nnn` is almost always the first argument; I keep this convention, this helps memory).
3. You put the “result macro” (a single control sequence token) in the “sensitive place”. Expanding a macro once is a very basic operation; this works in every context where expansion takes place.

Let's apply this strategy to your problem:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\NewDocumentCommand{\prepareStuff}{ m O{#3} m }{%
  \def#1{(#2,#3)}% you could compute things here using \edef or \cs_new:Npx
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \prepareStuff{\coords}{1}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot coordinates {(0,0) \coords};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, you could do `\prepareStuff{\coords}[1]{1}` with the same effect here (showing you can use optional args as requested, or anything `\NewDocumentCommand` allows) and put this call in other places, like before `\begin{document}`.

Note: I used `\def` inside `\prepareStuff` in case you want to call `\prepareStuff` several times with the same “result macro” (here, `\coords`). For cases where this doesn't make sense, you can of course use `\newcommand`.

Also, `\def` performs a *local* definition (its effect is limited to the current TeX group); if you want a global one, use `\gdef` instead.

Comment: Nice! You could use `O{#3}` instead of hard-coding the default there.

Comment: This is in, thanks for the idea!